# A suprising usage of the present simple tense: "Why do you ask?" vs. "Why are you asking?"

Tags: present-tense, tense-agreement

Here is an extract from a TV series:

> [P1] - Did your husband have a physical disability?
>
> [P2] - He had a bad knee.[...] **Why do you ask?**

I was taught at school that when I'm talking about an action which is in progress, I should use **the present continuous tense**. The first person (P1) asked the question a few seconds ago, but still if I wanted to use a present tense, **the present continuous seems** to be the only one appriopriate.

Why did the second person (P2) used **the present simple tense**? Would it be correct to use **the present continuous tense** instead?

Edit: I'm asking why the person used **Why do you ask?** instead of **Why are you asking?**.

Comment: Question is: is the husband still alive?

Comment: No, he's dead. Why does it matter? It's still a **present** tense.

Comment: Related: **[“Why are you asking?” versus “Why do you ask?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/139853/why-are-you-asking-versus-why-do-you-ask)**

Comment: Which part are you asking about?  Why she says "Why do you ask" instead of "why did you ask" or "why are you asking"?

Comment: @stangdon, I'm  asking why the person used *Why do you ask*? instead of *Why are you asking?*

Comment: That's what my question was about, I thought you were asking about **had** a bad knee, since it was obvious (to me) **Why do you ask?** is being said... it's because P1 is asking now, P2 could easily have also said: **Why are you asking?**

Comment: @CopperKettle, thanks for the link. However, I don't think any of the users in ELU answered my question. The accepted answer is clear, but it refers to what I already know. It doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Sorry, my question was ambiguous. But why (and when) is it corrent to say *why do you ask* instead of *why are you asking*? It contradicts one of basic rules of the grammar. I mean, if a native speaker said it, it clearly doesn't. But why? It seems wrong to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Why do you ask?
> - Why did you ask?
> - Why have you asked?
> - Why are you asking?

Any of these responses are possible.

The continuous aspect of "Why are you asking?" establishes the act of asking as an ongoing process -- a process with a duration.   In the present tense, this implies that the process began in the past and will end (if it ends at all) in the future.

That can work.   In this context, the asking began in the immediate past of a few scant seconds ago and continues through the immediate future of an instant or two from now.

For me (and apparently for P2) the present continuous isn't the most natural choice.   From my perspective, the act of asking is not an ongoing process.   The action *had* a brief duration that began when the question was posed and ended when the question was answered.   This duration has no relevance to the follow-up question.   I regard the act of asking as [telic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telicity), as a self-contained action the internal components of which don't matter to me.

The perfect aspect of "Why have you asked?" makes sense from a telic perspective.   The thing that exists in the present tense is not the action of asking but the *result* of asking.

That can work.   In this context, we can regard the asking as a fact rather than an action or a duration.

Again, I don't find this option to be the most natural choice.   My native dialect is American, and many American dialects prefer to avoid perfect constructions when they are unnecessary.   In many cases, a past-tense action is enough to imply a present-tense situation or fact.

The past tense of "Why did you ask?" simply places the action of asking in the past.

That can work.   The act of asking starts with posing the question and ends with accepting an answer.   If we assume that P1 accepted the answer given, then the action can simply be placed in the past.

For me, this exchange is too immediate to be comfortably placed in the past.   I am more likely to consider the question and answer exchange to be so recent that it is part of the present moment.

This leaves us with the option that P2 chose.   "Why do you ask?" is a present simple construction.   A more descriptive name for this construction is the *present indefinite*.

Although it is called "simple", there is nothing simple about interpreting the indefinite aspect.   The entire point of the indefinite aspect is that we do not know from the verb form alone what aspect the clause has.   It could be habitual, periodic, iterative, gnomic -- the list goes on and on.

The specific aspect is often indicated adverbially:

- Why do you sometimes ask?
- Why do you frequently ask?
- Why do you always ask?
- Why do you ever ask?
- Why do you ask at a time like this?

You've been taught to prefer the present continuous construction in order to *avoid* unintentionally implying any of these aspects that the indefinite construction allows.   The continuous aspect implies an immediacy and a concreteness that the indefinite aspect cannot express on its own.

In your example conversation, this seems to be an intentional and purposeful implication.   P2 doesn't care about the duration of the action, or whether the action is complete or ongoing.   When it comes to placement in time, P2 considers the action recent enough to be included in the present moment.

You didn't cite a source for this bit of dialogue.   I can't check whether my assumption is correct.   If it makes sense for P2 to assume that P1 *habitually* asks this question, then it makes sense for P2 to imply the habitual aspect with an indefinite construction.

Comment: Thanks for this very comprehensive answer. The source of the dialogue is one of the episodes of *Criminal minds:suspect behavior*: http://vodlocker.com/09yb2dmvbsnr, approximately 8:52  I think in this case it means "Why do you ask at a time like this?" and it isn't habitual, is it?

Comment: Ah, I see.  This is dialogue from a police procedural.  In that context, the habitual aspect makes sense.  Investigators *are* in the habit of asking questions.  Here's another perspective:  This "Why do you ask?" means something like "Why does it matter?" or "Why do you care?"  Those questions have a [stative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stative_verb) sense.  P2 avoids "Why are you asking?" for the same reason she would avoid "Why is it mattering?" or "Why are you caring?"  We use continuous verb constructions to lend a stative sense to dynamic verbs.  Already stative verbs don't need that.

Answer (score 3):

When a question is asked, it remains asked until answered. As we say, "Is there a question on the table?" So there's no need to use the progressive to indicate that the question is "on the table". The progressive reveals the speaker's attitude towards answering the question: the choice of the progressive reveals that the person being questioned considers the question to be *in limbo* so to speak -- possibly viable, possibly not, but that it may receive an answer if the reason for the question is found to be satisfactory.

Comment: Thanks. That helps. Could you please tell me if  *ask* is the only verb which can be used in the present simple tense instead of in the present continuous tense? Is *ask* the only exeption to the rule that when we refer to an action which is in progress, we should use the present continuous tense? I don't mean the static verbs or verbs which change their meaning depending on the tense. That's clear to me. I'm curious if there are more nuances like the one with *ask* or if you can somehow extend your answer (the rule you described) to other verbs.

Comment: So "Why **did** you ask?" would be felicitous, provided that the question has already been answered?

Comment: @CopperKettle: "Why did you ask?" would not be unusual at all, and it isn't infelicitous.

Comment: @user2738748: Almost any verb can be used in the present simple tense, even when the action is in progress, especially in questions with "do".  *Why is the moth flying around the candle?* and *Why does the moth fly around the candle?* might receive identical answers, but they're not identical questions.

Comment: @CopperKettle:  Why were you asking?

Comment: Oh. Indeed. And that again will indicate some suspicion on part of the pronouncer, I guess.

Comment: @TRomano, I know that (almost) every verb can be used in the present simple tense. And I know and understand why questions in different tenses would receive different answers. My question was rather: are there any other nuances, exeptions like using  the progressive to indicate that the question is "on the table"? I mean situdations when I would use the present continuous tense, because an action is in progress (as I was taught at school), but the present simple tense is right. You gave an explanation for just one verb. Are there more verbs which could surprise me?

Comment: @user2738748: Now that you know that the simple present can be used to refer to actions-in-progress (but without any emphasis on their ongoingness) there are no longer any verbs that should surprise you in this way.

Comment: "Why did you ask?" doesn't sound unusual to you? It sounds very weird to me unless the question is much further in the past. Even then I would usually expect it to be followed by what it was that was asked. Such as "Why did you ask about my husband's disability?" unless *did* is stressed as in, "Didn't it seem strange to you I asked about ...", "You're right, why **did** you ask?"

Comment: @ TRomano, no, so far you have explained to me that the verb "ask" may be used in the the present simple tense  to refer to actions-in-progress. You haven't said anything about any other verb (exept for your last comment). And this is my question: why would I use any other verb in the present simple tense for an ongoing action? I understand your exaple, but it refers to only one verb. Could you generalise your answer and describe the problem for the rest of verbs?

Comment: @DRF:  CopperKettle said "provided that the question has already been answered."  To my mind, when the question has been answered, its action is "completed" and so "did ask" is OK for the question *is* a thing of the past. One might also say "Why have you asked?"  I'd probably say "Why do you want to know?" even after having given an answer.

Comment: @user2738748.  The "problem" is that the continuous is not always a  *neutral* acknowledgment of an event's happening-now aspect, that, and nothing more than that. It is sometimes more than that. But that problem is context-driven.  I have no list of verbs that have this gotcha, but verbs referring to the mental state of one's interlocutor are a good place to begin if you felt inclined to compile such a list yourself. Does that satisfy you? Is that satisfying you?  Satisfaction is not an event, right?

Comment: @TRomano, first of all, thank you for your patience (this is not irony).  I know that state verbs shouldn't be used in the continuous form and that I shoudn't say *I'm wanting to go home*. It doesn't suprise me. I see your point. In a very similar situation I could say *Why do you say that?* instead of *Why are you saying that?*.

Comment: @user2738748 Except that we *can* and *do* say "I'm *wanting* to go home" in addition to "I want to go home."  Perhaps the continuous there informs the listener that the desire to go home is not merely an incipient state, or that this is no impetuous expression of a wish, but that it is a state now in full bloom or close to it.

Comment: @TRomano, is it an infromal English or is it something that I can use during an exam or at a conference? Could you also think of an example when  *I'm wanting to go home* would be more appriopriate or precise than *I want to go home*, when *you* would use it? This is one of the exeptions I meant:)

Comment: @user2738748: This is conversational English, as most things are which have to do with the expression of feelings, and as many things are which use the progressive. Departure from the expected or ordinary tense will have some nuanced meaning (assuming it comes from the mouth of a fluent speaker). Maybe your girlfriend or spouse is not having the best time of her life at an office party to which you've dragged her and she says to you "I'm wanting to go home."  Maybe that continuous form is not as peremptory as "I want to go home" and is leaving the decision to you, how much longer to stay.

Comment: @TRomano, I see. Thank you for the explanation and your time. It was very interesting and enlightening (again, no irony intended).